# WSO2 API Publisher SSO with identity Server error 403

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I follow the guide https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/extending-api-manager/saml2-sso/configuring-identity-server-as-idp-for-sso/#configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-saml-20-sso-identity-provider but getting

Error 403 : Forbidden

The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the requested resource

when try to login to publisher -

Comment: This is too little information to provide any reasonable advice. If it's for publisher - does the user get the publisher and creator role?

Comment: Yes, I did grant

Comment: Are you observing any errors in either the API Manager or the IS server while performing the Sign-in operation? If yes, can you share the stack trace in the question? Further, can you check whether the User you are trying to log in with is having the required roles to access the Publisher portal (Internal/Publisher and Internal/creator roles)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer applies if you are running the API Manager and Identity Server with separated User Stores configured. Apply the following configurations on top of the instructions mentioned in the [Docs](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/extending-api-manager/saml2-sso/configuring-identity-server-as-idp-for-sso/#configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-saml-20-sso-identity-provider) and try out the scenario.

1. Add two roles in the Identity Server named `publisher` and `creator` without any permissions and assign both to the User that you are using to log in. *You can skip this part if you already have roles assigned to the User in the Identity Server to do a Role Mapping in the API Manager server.*
2. Open the Service Provider you have created in the Identity Server and go to  `Inbound Authentication Configuration` > `SAML2 Web SSO Configuration` and click on `Edit`. Tick the `Enable Attribute Profile` and `Include Attributes in the Response Always` and `Update`
3. Expand the `Claim Configuration` of the Service Provider that is created in the Identity Server and select the `Use Local Claim Dialect` option. Then, click on `Add Claim URI` and in the appeared drop-down select `http://wso2.org/claims/role` and tick the `Mandatory Claim`. Once done, update the configurations.
4. Open the Identity Provider that is created under the API Manager server and expand the `Role Configuration` section.

   - Click on `Add Role Mapping` and enter the following

     - `Identity Provider Role`: `publisher` *(use the correct role name that you have assigned in the Identity Server)*
     - `Local Role`: `Internal/publisher`
   - Click on `Add Role Mapping` and enter the following

     - `Identity Provider Role`: `creator` *(use the correct role name that you have assigned in the Identity Server)*
     - `Local Role`: `Internal/creator`

   Update the configurations.

Once the configurations are saved, now try logging into the Publisher Portal of the API Manager with the specific user.